# Creating a case-control cohort in R

Tags: r, multicollinearity, matching, case-control-study

I have a variable: hyperglycemia and a bunch of other variables like Age, Gender, BMI, many other variables. I would like to create a matched case control group case being those with hyperglycemia and control are those without hyperglycemia.

I would like to match for potential confounders but since I have a lot of variables I am unsure how to go about creating a properly matched cohort.

This is what I did so far. I ran a logistic regression with hyperglycemia as my dependent variable and all the other variables as dependent. I used VIF >10 as a cut off for multicollinearity and dropped variables one by one until they were all below 10 to have a fairly reliable regression table. Then, I chose the variables significantly associated with hyperglycemia and used the MatchIT package on R to match for those. When I did a t.test and wilcox test id get high pvalues meaning their means arent different after matching even though they were before and I am assuming that means the matching worked.

Is this a reliable way to go about it or is there an easier/more reliable route?